# How do I create a new instance of an ItemCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working with WPF in the MVVM pattern.

I need an ItemCollection instance to put in my ViewModel, which I can then bind to the Items property of a DataGrid on my view.

I am going to be programatically adding buttons to this ItemCollection.

I notice it doesn't have a public constructor, and is sealed. Is there any way to get my hands on an instance? Is there any static/factory methods which will return an instance?

Thanks

Comment: You don't add UI elements in the ViewModel in MVVM. Use an `ObservableCollection<ICommand>`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a workaround to create an empty `ItemCollection`:

```
var myCollection = new DataGrid().Items;
```

Comment: What would you do with this? Items collections tend to be read only so you couldn't bind or assign them AFAIK so not sure this is really useful.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't create one and no, you do not even need one. Use the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property to data bind your data source to the grid instead, as is typical in WPF.

The only time when you interact with an `ItemsCollection` is when directly accessing the `Items` property of an `ItemsControl`, i.e. when manually working with the data instead of binding. This type of manipulation is entirely contrary to the spirit of MVVM, so you are not missing anything.

Comment: Or when creating a Custom Control derived from ItemsControl, which is a completely different story

Comment: Works great, I binded the ItemsSource to the ObservableCollection<ICommand> recommended by @HighCore. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's ever a case where you'd need to create a new instance of it. `ItemsCollection` was intended to be used internally as @Jon implies. The `ObservableCollection` class was intended to be used for presenting a read/write collection, which is what the OP really wants. Ultimately, it boils down to defining a view model, which you can specify a template for (in OP's case, a `Button`) and binding a collection of those to the control. That _is_ the MVVM pattern; what OP asked for _is not_.